# Robust Javascript parser in Java

Tags: java, javascript

I am looking for a *robust* Javascript parser written in Java - by which I mean a Javascript parser that is able to handle most real world Javascript.

I am only interested in *parsing* Javascript, *not* in executing it.

I have found Rhino:
http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.js-engine.rhino/browse_thread/thread/1eff23a8ee57b991

Am I missing anything? Is this the best solution?

Thank you!
Misha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's probably the best Java one.  As you probably know, it's developed by Mozilla (though it's not used by their browsers), and it's also [bundled](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html#jsengine) by Sun.

Comment: In other words, it's built-in in Java's standard library, see the package `javax.script`.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately JDK 6 is out for me, as Mac support for this platform seems to be ... not quite there :(

Comment: @Misha, you don't have to use JDK 6.  The [download](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/js/rhino1_7R2.zip) includes js-14.jar, which supports as early as 1.4.

Comment: Thank you. I meant I can't use javax.script as that is part of JDK 6. Thank you!